# How to select an element only if the next element is of a specific type using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Given the following XML:

```
<w:p>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:ins>
        <w:t>sections</w:t>
   </w:ins>
   <w:pPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-CA"/>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
     <w:t>I am</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I want to select the `w:pPr` elements that are followed by either `w:ins` or `w:del` elements.

I tried:

```
doc.xpath("w:pPr[following-sibling::w:ins[1] or following-sibling::w:del[1]]")
```

which still returns the second `w:pPr` element which is followed by a `w:r` element so it's not what I'm looking for.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath expression:

```
//w:pPr[following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()='w:del' or name()='w:ins']]
```

Comment: I tried it and the result is that it still returns the pPr element that is followed by the w: r element

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. This works. How can I apply this to only one paragraph. If I have the paragraph, paragraph_1.xpath(...) for example?

Comment: I'm not sure I've correctly understood your issue... If you want the first occurrence only, then just add `[1]` predicate

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.  I have a document with many paragraphs. I do some analysis using one paragraph at a time.  If I wanted to find all of the w:pPr elements each of which must be followed by either a w:ins or w:del  in a specific paragraph how would I change the xpath statement?

Comment: Still not sure that I got your point :) If you want to get `w:pPr` from a specific paragraph, you could add appropriate parent/ancestor element: `//w:paragraph[...]//w:pRp[...]`. Use predicate or index to match exact paragraph. You can update your question with bigger piece of `HTML` sample to make your issue clearer

Comment: In my app I take a document that is made up of many paragraphs.  I take only paragraphs that contain w:ins or w:del elements.  Now I take that nodeset and examine each one at a time for my app. I was using the xpath as follows:nokogiri_xml_doc.xpath('//w:p[w:ins or w:del]')to get the w:pPr elements that match my criteria.  I understand that using '//' will search the entire document and not just the paragraph that I'm currently analysing. How could I just examine the text in my current paragraph: paragraph_1.xpath('./w:pPr[following...')?

Comment: Yep, `//` means search in the whole document while `.//` points to current context. Note that `./w:pPr` means that `w:pRp` is a *direct child* of a predefined paragraph, `.//w:pPr` means *descendant-or-self*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145430/discussion-between-chell-and-andersson).